# How does signal and background depend on declination

Tags: astronomy, neutrinos

Considering a neutrino telescope, such as the ANTARES, how is the signal and background dependant on the declination.

Answer (score 0):

For the IceCube Neutrino telescope, the proceeding by Kopper et al. (2015, https://pos.sissa.it/236/1081) shows in Fig. 4 the dependence of the signal and the predicted background on the declination

[image]
(Image taken from https://pos.sissa.it/236/1081/pdf)

Leaving details aside, the different behaviour of the components on the declination can mainly be explained with different shielding from the Earth and atmospheric thickness for different zenith angles.

The following sketch from Ahlers et al. (2018, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-018-6369-9) visualises where the different components can come from.

[image]

(Image taken from https://media.springernature.com/original/springer-static/image/art:10.1140/epjc/s10052-018-6369-9/MediaObjects/10052_2018_6369_Fig3_HTML.png)

For the Antares Neutrino Telescope the situation is very similar, just with much less events and the position in the Mediterranean Sea means that zenith angle and declination are not directly related like on the south pole.